# Why is my view file moving all my head content into the body section?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm very confused by how the `application.html.erb` file and the view files combine.  I have in my `application.html.erb` file the following (minimized the content for brevity):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Bootstrap Css -->
    <link href="/bootstrap-assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <%= yield :head %>
  </head>
<body>
   <nav>
      <!--Long navbar section -->
   </nav>
  <%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

In my view file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- View Specific Stylesheet -->
    <link href="/css/ViewSpecific.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <!-- View Specific Body -->
</body>
```

What I would expect is that when these 2 files combine, the View specific stylesheet load in the `<head>` section, and the View Specific Body load in the `<body>` section.  The final result actually sends the view specific stylesheet to the `<body>` section, after the `navbar` from `application.html.erb` is already loaded.  This obviously produces the unwanted result that part of my body is loading before the stylsheet is loaded, and the first second the user views the page everything looks terrible.

Answer (score 1):

You should make use of `content_for` if you want to render the view-specific `head` into the head section of `application.html.erb`. Use

```
<% content_for :head do %>
 <!-- View specific head section -->
  <link href="/css/ViewSpecific.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<% end %>
```

Since you yield `:head` in the `application.html.erb`, thats all to be done. And you don't need `html` tags in the views.

For more, see http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper/content_for